# Is OTCMKTS stock price strictly linked to the foreign traded stock price?

Tags: stocks

I know OTCMKTS is OTC Markets Group. However, is the OTCMKTS stock price strictly linked to the foreign traded stock price?

For example, when I search "OTCMKTS: ZTCOY" and "zte stock hk (HKG: 0763)", I feel they have very similar prices. "OTCMKTS: ZTCOY" indicates the price in the US while "HKG: 0763" indicates the price traded in Hong Kong. I also searched in my broker. It shows up two choices: ZTCOF ZTE CORP SHS H and ZTCOY ZTE CORP UNSPONSORED ADR. So, which one should I buy?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are share prices for a company which is listed on multiple exchanges, under multiple currencies, kept in synch?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/are-share-prices-for-a-company-which-is-listed-on-multiple-exchanges-under-mult)

Comment: ZTCOY is an ADR. 5-letter tickers that end with Y are ADRs.

Comment: The link answers some questions. But it is not exactly the same. The link talks about a company listed in two different stock exchanges. But, my question is about OTCMKTS.

Comment: Relevant: [Which should I buy: F shares or Y shares?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/127383)

Comment: [FAQ on F Shares - OTC Markets](https://www.otcmarkets.com/files/FAQ-F-Shares.pdf)

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which should I buy: F shares or Y shares?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/127383/which-should-i-buy-f-shares-or-y-shares)